# Windows 7 randomly drops to Basic UI after full screen apps

Tags: windows-7, aero

Sometimes when I close a fullscreen application in Windows 7, it drops me back to the Basic UI.
Windows has indicated that the problem is that the DWM service has stopped, but I only thought it didn't do anything when a full screen app was on...
What do I do to fix it, aside from clicking the troubleshoot link in "Personalize"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably because of a driver crash. Try updating your video drivers.

Comment: Hmm haven't done that. I'll get back to you as soon as i can.

Answer (score 1):

This is often not a crash.  It is based on the application you are runnning.  There are certain DirectDraw APIs that are not supported in DWM.  When an application opens DirectDraw in a way that calls these APIs, DWM turns itself off.  This could be because the application creates and Overlay or certain surface types.  When the application exits, it will go back.

Comment: But that's the thing. it *isnt* coming back!